# Install Snow Leopard without Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro, install, leopard

I have a MacBook, which was running Leopard.

It got corrupted, and even I want to upgrade to Snow Leopard.
So I purchased Snow Leopard Retail Box.

Now, I want to install Snow Leopard, but I cannot start Leopard.
How can I perform clean install of Snow Leopard, without needing Leopard.

Videos Links are welcomed too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above [now below as this is the 'accepted' answer] instructions will install Snow Leopard - but not technically a clean install.

To do so follow the above steps but enter Disk Utility after choosing the language in the installer.  You can wipe it from there.

Stolen from Macs.com

the Snow Leopard installer will ask which language you want to use as the main language. Make your selection and click the right arrow key.

The Install Mac OS X screen will display. Click the ‘Utilities’ button.

In the Apple menu bar, select ‘Disk Utilities’ from the Utilities menu.

Disk Utilities will launch. Select one of the following instructions, depending on what you wish to do.

Erase a Volume. Use these instructions to erase an entire volume. Be sure to back up all of your data first.

Format a Hard Drive. Use these instructions if you wish to erase an entire hard drive, including any volumes/partitions it may contain, and not create any new volumes/partitions. Be sure to back up all of your data first.

Partition a Hard Drive. Use these instructions if you wish to erase and partition a hard drive. Be sure to back up all of your data first.

When you have finished using Disk Utility, select ‘Quit’ from the Disk Utility menu.

You will be returned to the Snow Leopard Installer to continue the installation.

Answer (score 5):

Insert the Snow Leopard DVD into your DVD drive. Reboot the computer and hold down the Option key (newer keyboard call it "Alt"). After a few seconds, the screen will show your hard drive(s) and the DVD. Select the DVD, this will start the Installer.

If your previous installation of Leopard was corrupted by a failing hard drive, you will not be able to install Snow Leopard though (the Installer won't let you). In that case you must first replace the drive.

Comment: you can also hold down `c` to boot from the disc

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the Snow Leopard Retail disk not booting. I copied it to a USB drive using disk utility and booted from there. Typical install process from then on.